# Why ls | grep * isn't displaying anything?

Tags: bash, command-line, grep, ls

if i do ls the output is:
[image]

but if i do ls | grep complex*
or `ll | grep complex*` or even `ll | grep *` or `ll | grep * | less`
the output is always:
[image]

This is confusing to me.

I want to get a list of all files that start with `complex*` FYI if '*' == anything.

Comment: Because the shell expands `*`. If you want to get a list of all files that start with 'complex*' that'd be `ls complex*`.

Comment: Insert an `echo` to see what bash makes with your second command:  `ls | echo grep *`

Comment: Worse, if `complex_assignment_other.c` file contains a line with phrase `complex_assignment.c`, (say `// this function is defined in file complex_assignment.c`) that line will be printed on terminal...

Comment: @Cyrus, you can also educate OP about `set -vx`...

Answer (score 3):

you're looking for:

```
ls | grep 'complex.*'
```

or, better:

```
ls complex*
```

Comment: Thanks a lot map, What a dummy mistake :p

Comment: i think everyone has made almost this exact mistake once or twice ;)

Answer (score 1):

By default `*`is meant for [[ globbing ]](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html).

If you have a file named `*` or one containing `*`, you could do

```
ls | grep \*
```

or

```
ls | grep '*'
```

If you are looking for literal `*` in the files you could do :

```
grep '*' *  # second will glob all the files in the current dir.
```

If you wish to use see all the files which have the word Complex*_plus_something* do:

```
grep -E '\<Complex[_[:alnum:]]+' *
```

Here the `+` is for one or more and `\<` matches the empty string at the beginning of a word :-)

Comment: yeah thanks a lot I missed the quotes

Comment: The trailing `.*` in the final example is completely superfluous; see my answer for a detailed explanation.

Comment: @tripleee : Indeed it is superfluous here . Thankyou. I needed the '+' option because I don't want to catch the string "Complex" itself but "Complex1","Complex2" and so on.

Comment: Though `.` will also match comma, space, etc. Maybe you want `'\<Complex[[:alnum:]]+'` instead.

Comment: @tripleee : point noted :-) and edit the answer

Comment: Hmmm, though `[:alnum:]` doesn't match underscore -- perhaps then `[_[:alnum:]]`?  Sorry for not testing that detail!

Comment: @tripleee : Why not add this too ;-)

Comment: I would, but code edits are discouraged; the preferred procedure is to leave it up to the answer's author to react to comments, or leave things be.

Comment: @tripleee Well, `\<` is not seen very common in regex, I wanted to leave a note on that too..

Answer (score 1):

To simplify my explanation, I won't speak of the hidden files.

Because your command doesn't mean what you're trying to achieve.

The * is very special for bash and doesn't have the meaning you think. It is a character the shell will replace with all the file names it can correspond to in the current directory.
An example :

```
adrien@adrienLT:~/foo$ ls
adrien@adrienLT:~/foo$ touch foo
adrien@adrienLT:~/foo$ ls
foo
adrien@adrienLT:~/foo$ ls | grep *
foo
```

% The above is equivalent to 
`$ ls | grep foo`

```
adrien@adrienLT:~/foo$ touch bar
adrien@adrienLT:~/foo$ ls | grep *
```

% The above is equivalent to 
`$ ls | grep bar foo`, it will output something if the word "bar" is **IN** the file foo.

See there, an example with more files :

```
adrien@adrienLT:~/foo$ touch bar foo foobar
adrien@adrienLT:~/foo$ echo "bar" > foo
adrien@adrienLT:~/foo$ echo "bar" > foobar
adrien@adrienLT:~/foo$ ls | grep *
foo:bar
foobar:bar
```

**Now, to do what you want to achieve**, you can use * to your advantage :

```
adrien@adrienLT:~/foo$ ls foo*
foo  foobar
```

But if there is a directory that correspond your research, it will list its content.

```
adrien@adrienLT:~/foo$ mkdir foodir
adrien@adrienLT:~/foo$ for i in {0..10}; do touch "foodir/$i"; done
adrien@adrienLT:~/foo$ ls foo*
foo  foobar

foodir:
0  1  10  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

So you may want to use the option -d not to list their content :

```
adrien@adrienLT:~/foo$ ls -d foo*
foo  foobar  foodir
```

But if your search becomes more complicated, I can only advice to use a more powerful tool such as find.

This one uses globbing (the * I explained above)

```
adrien@adrienLT:~/foo$ find . -type f -name "foo*"
./foo
./foobar
```

This one uses regular expression but that is a tool you need to study a bit to be able to handle without loosing your hair :

```
adrien@adrienLT:~/foo$ find . -type f -regex ".*/foo[^/]*$"
./foo
./foobar
```

To explain a bit, the above search the current directory (.) for files only (-type f) which match a particular pattern (-regex ".*/foo[^/]*$").

This pattern is "anything followed by slash foo followed by anything except slash until the end of the file".

Comment: haha! nice abt the hair :D

Comment: and nice explanation too. Thanks a lot for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

You have two mistakes: `*` doesn't mean "anything" in regular expressions, and because you didn't quote it, the shell expanded it.

If you have three files, the result of `ls | grep *` after wildcard expansion is something like

```
ls | grep bar baz foo
```

The behavior of `grep` in this situation is that it simply ignores standard input (this may not be documented and/or completely standard and/or well-defined), so `ls |` is ignored and useless. You end up looking for the name of the first matching file in the other two.

Now, the regular expression you used searches for `comple` anywhere in the input (`x*` means zero or more occurrences of `x`; if there are zero, the expression will match, and it doesn't prevent matching on, say, `incomplete`, so you might as way omit this). The correct expression is `^complex` to find this word only at beginning of line (don't forget the quotes; `^` is also a shell metacharacter) or just `complex` to find it anywhere on a line.

If the point is just to enumerate, you don't need `grep` or regular expressions at all, or `ls`, either!

```
echo complex*
```

will show the names of all the matching files, or if you want one per line,

```
printf '%s\n' complex*
```

(This is also more robust, so generally a better approach. Avoid both `ls` and `echo` in scripts if you can.)

To loop over matching files, you cannot reliably use `ls`.

```
for f in complex*; do
    printf '%s\n' "$f"
done
```

As a special case, `grep '*'` looks for a literal asterisk. Some regex tools (rightfully) fail with an error message for invalid regex (including *BSD `grep`; the special case is in GNU `grep`).

Comment: learnt a lot of things, from now on i will not use ls and echo in my bash scripts, Thanks a lot for help